# Remove USB Accessory permission dialog

Tags: android, usb, adk

I am working on an application which uses USB accessory.When I attach device to arduino it asks for usb permission and it has checkbox in dialog "use by default".When I checked and press ok then it should save permission and do not ask me again but it is asking for permission every time I attach USB.I want to save permission is there any way to save this?

My Code loooks like

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (mInputStream != null && mOutputStream != null) {
        // streams were not null");
        return;
    }
    // streams were null");
    UsbAccessory[] accessories = mUsbManager.getAccessoryList();
    UsbAccessory accessory = (accessories == null ? null : accessories[0]);
    if (accessory != null) {
        if (mUsbManager.hasPermission(accessory)) {
            openAccessory(accessory);
        } else {
            synchronized (mUsbReceiver) {
                if (!mPermissionRequestPending) {
                    mUsbManager.requestPermission(accessory,
                            mPermissionIntent);
                    mPermissionRequestPending = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And Android manifest file looks

```
 <activity
        android:name="pkg.sarvajal.soochakdroid.Main"
        android:label="@string/Home" 
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED" />
             <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_DETACHED" />
        </intent-filter>


        <meta-data
            android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED"
            android:resource="@xml/accessory_filter" />
    </activity>
```

Accessory filter is like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<usb-accessory manufacturer="Manufacturer" model="Model" version="1.0" />
<usb-device vendor-id="0x0403" product-id="0x0403" />
</resources>
```

My BroadcastReceiver code

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mUsbReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (ACTION_USB_PERMISSION.equals(action)) {
            synchronized (this) {
                //UsbAccessory accessory = UsbManager.getAccessory(intent);
                UsbAccessory accessory = (UsbAccessory) intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_ACCESSORY);
                if (intent.getBooleanExtra(
                        UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED, false)) {
                    Flag_USB_Attached = true;
                    Flag_Count_USB_Attached = 0;
                    Flag_Count_USB_Restart_App = 0;
                    openAccessory(accessory);
                    String strdatetime =responce_date();
                    //sendSMS_background(phoneNumber, "USB Cable Connected  at "+strdatetime);


                } else {
                    // USB permission denied
                }
            }
        } else if (UsbManager.ACTION_USB_ACCESSORY_DETACHED.equals(action)) {
            //UsbAccessory accessory = UsbManager.getAccessory(intent);
            UsbAccessory accessory = (UsbAccessory) intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_ACCESSORY);
            if (accessory != null && accessory.equals(mAccessory)) {
                // accessory detached
                Flag_USB_Attached = false;
                Flag_Count_USB_Attached = 0;
                closeAccessory();
                String strdatetime =responce_date();
                //sendSMS_background(phoneNumber, "Communication Stopped! \n USB Cable Disconnected  at "+strdatetime);
                //SMS_USB();

            }
        }
}
```

And Settingup accessory code

```
/ Setting up accessory
private void setupAccessory() {
    //mUsbManager = UsbManager.getInstance(this);
    mUsbManager  = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
    mPermissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(
            ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0);
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION);
    filter.addAction(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_ACCESSORY_DETACHED);
    registerReceiver(mUsbReceiver, filter);
    if (getLastNonConfigurationInstance() != null) {
        mAccessory = (UsbAccessory) getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
        openAccessory(mAccessory);
    }
}
// Opening Accessory Mode
private void openAccessory(UsbAccessory accessory) {
    mFileDescriptor = mUsbManager.openAccessory(accessory);
    if (mFileDescriptor != null) {
        mAccessory = accessory;
        FileDescriptor fd = mFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor();
        mInputStream = new FileInputStream(fd);
        mOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(fd);
        Thread thread = new Thread(null, this, "OpenAccessoryTest");
        thread.start();
        // Accessory opened
    } else {
        // failed to open accessory
    }
}
// close Accessory
private void closeAccessory() {
    try {
        // T.cancel();
        if (mFileDescriptor != null) {
            mFileDescriptor.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
    } finally {
        mFileDescriptor = null;
        mAccessory = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use the shared preference of the native ,but i am not sure unless i understand your question completely .so send me some snippet of your code or screen shot of your code.

Comment: @Balaji Sabdhar M I have edited my question with code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Android USB host documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html), your application has permission to access the device until the device is disconnected. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12388914/usb-device-access-pop-up-supression) provides a solution to suppress the permission dialog. Create an intent filter in your manifest file and provide the device information in an xml file. This would enable enumerating the device using a broadcast receiver.

Another reference is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726583/bypass-android-usb-host-permision-confirmation-dialog). The latter is meant for rooted devices and I haven't tried it personally.

Edit:

Manifest File: I register my Broadcast Receiver in the manifest file.

```
<receiver android:name="MyReceiver">
                 <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
                 </intent-filter>
                 <meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
                    android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />
</receiver>
```

For the sake of convenience, I have my Broadcast Receiver in a separate class:

```
public class PmrtReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String action = intent.getAction();
        if(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED.equals(action)){

            Toast.makeText(context, "Device Detected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        } else if(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED.equals(action)){

            Toast.makeText(context, "Device Detached",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

    }

};
```

I did not have to do anything else to suppress the permission dialog.

Look into the USB Missile Launcher example from the Android Samples. Your device filtr should be something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<resources>
    <usb-device vendor-id="1234" product-id="5678" />  
</resources>
```

You have the VID and PID as hexadecimal numbers.

Comment: I did the same coding but no luck

Comment: Can you share the accessory filter?

Comment: I have edited my question with accessory filter code

Comment: The VID and PID should be integers, not hexadecimal numbers. How are you registering the device using intent filter? Are you doing it programmatically or have you registered the receiver in the manifest file?

Comment: I have also added some information. Register your intent filter with the action USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED. Refer the USB Missile launcher example

Comment: I have edited my code as per your suggestions and tried it out with arduino but it is asking for permission

Comment: Does this happen when you plug the device every time or every time you  launch the app? Are you using any pending intent to obtain permission? I am using the same procedure. I am able to suppress the dialog

Comment: It happens everytime I launch app. I have used pendingintent for permission

Comment: I put another solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57281141/3268303