# Persistent USB Permission in android app upon reattachment

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-11, android-usb

I have an application running in Android 11 that I am packaging with my own device. No other applications will ever be installed on this device. Also, given the age of the hardware, the device will never receive any Android updates.

I need to provide UART communication for my app to work as intended. Whenever I connect a USB cable, I get a pop up asking to grant permissions to the USB port and it works perfectly once those permissions are granted.

The challenge: Whenever the USB cable is disconnected and reconnected, I keep getting the USB permission pop up, which is, while a great thing from security standpoint and is generally considered the best practice, is proving to be a little annoying considering my use case.

Is there a way for me to simulate user granting the USB port permission without displaying the popup?
Note: I was able to suppress the popup, and store the granted permissions in app's local storage.

Here is my code :
**Manifest**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host" />
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.***themename***"
        android:directBootAware="true"
        tools:targetApi="31">
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
<receiver
            android:name=".USBReceiver.UsbDeviceReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.packagename.USB_PERMISSION" />
                <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
                <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_DETACHED" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
                android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />
        </receiver>
</application>
</manifest>
```

**UsbDeviceReceiver**

```
public class UsbDeviceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String ACTION_USB_PERMISSION = "com.example.packagename.USB_PERMISSION";
    private static final String ACTION_USB_ATTACHED = "android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED";
    private static final String ACTION_USB_DETACHED = "android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_DETACHED";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        UsbDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
        UsbManager usbManager = (UsbManager) context.getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
        if (ACTION_USB_ATTACHED.equals(action)) {
            // Handle USB device attachment
            showToast(context, "USB Device Attached");


                Log.d("USB PERMISSION","has permission:- "+usbManager.hasPermission(device));
                // Check if permission is already granted for this device
                synchronized (this) {
                    if (intent.getBooleanExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED, false)) {
                        if (device != null) {
                            Log.d("USB PERMISSION", "permission exists");
                            // Permission granted, open the device
                            SerialPortManagerSingleton.getInstance(context, null).openSerialPort((UsbManager) context.getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE));
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.d("USB PERMISSION", "permission does not exist");
                        // Permission denied
                        PendingIntent permissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                                context,
                                0,
                                new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION),
                                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S ? PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE : 0)
                        );
                        usbManager.requestPermission(device, permissionIntent);
                    }
                }

        } else if (ACTION_USB_DETACHED.equals(action)) {
            // Handle USB device detachment
            showToast(context, "USB Device Detached");
            SerialPortManagerSingleton.releaseInstance();
        } else if (ACTION_USB_PERMISSION.equals(action)) {
            synchronized (this) {
                if (intent.getBooleanExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED, false)) {
                    if (device != null) {
                        Log.d("USB PERMISSION", "granted permission");
                        Log.d("USB PERMISSION","has permission:- "+usbManager.hasPermission(device));
                        // Permission granted, open the device
                        SerialPortManagerSingleton.getInstance(context, null).openSerialPort((UsbManager) context.getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE));
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d("USB PERMISSION", "Permission denied for device " + device);
                    // Handle permission denial
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private void showToast(Context context, String message) {
        Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

**SerialPortMangerSingleton**

```
public class SerialPortManagerSingleton {
    private static SerialPortManager instance;
    private static SerialPortManager.CombinedSerialListener savedListener;

    public static synchronized SerialPortManager getInstance(Context appContext, SerialPortManager.CombinedSerialListener listener) {
        if (instance == null) {
//            savedListener = listener;
            Log.d("saved","listener "+savedListener);
            instance = new SerialPortManager(savedListener);
            instance.openSerialPort((UsbManager) appContext.getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE));
        } else {
            if (listener != null) {
                savedListener = listener;
                Log.d("saved","listener set"+savedListener);
                instance.setListener(savedListener);
            } else if (savedListener != null) {
                instance.setListener(savedListener);
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public static synchronized void releaseInstance() {
        if (instance != null) {
            instance.closeSerialPort();
            instance = null;
//            savedListener = null;
        }
    }
}
```

**to provide a brief explanation about above codes :**

- whenever the usb is detached/attached/permission granted, it triggers the usbReceiver broadcast and performs the tasks written in the provided code. Upon attachment it checks if the permission is already present, if true, it starts opening the serial port and on false it asks the permissions and once permission is granrted it does the same.

However upon every reattachment, it asks for permission shown in the picture[pop up whenever usb is attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKu6e.jpg)

- once i click on ok button, then it opens the serialport and everything works fine but when i reattach the usb it again popup the same that means it doesnot remember the permission across detachment and attachment.
  -If i try to open the serial port without giving permission for reattachment, then it throws error saying

```
UsbManager              pid-11465                            E  exception in UsbManager.openDevice
                                                                                                    java.lang.SecurityException: User has not given 10165/com.example.packagename permission to access device /dev/bus/usb/003/002
```

Any inputs are appreciated.

Comment: Related and possibly duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/57079079/2232127 - it seems that perhaps if you configure the receiver on an activity instead of a broadcast receiver, you could be able to grant the permission permanently

Comment: In any case, all examples I can find specify the intent-filter on an activity instead of a broadcast receiver. So I'd change that first before attempting anything further

Comment: Hi @JensV, I'm not sure if i have understood you correctly, did you mean configuring the receiver on an activity is here in manifest :
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Comment: Basically yes, if you want to do it with the MainActivity, you basically add another intent-filter to that. I suggest following the official docs closely with their examples and report back: https://developer.android.com/develop/connectivity/usb/accessory#manifest-example
If set up that way, you may get the permission dialog with the "Use by default for this USB device" switch.

Comment: I concur, but in this situation, including the intent-filter in the Main Activity will cause my app to restart that specific activity each time the USB is connected, which I'd like to avoid. Let me clarify my requirements:

Comment: 1) Every activity in my app needs to be capable of receiving messages from the serial port and carrying out specific actions.
2) If my app is currently active on a specific activity and running in the foreground, I want that activity to remain visible on the screen when the USB is reconnected.
3) I want the serial port to automatically open upon USB connection using "SerialPortManagerSingleton.getInstance(context, null).openSerialPort((UsbManager) context.getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE));". (without asking for a permission since we are giving it on first connection). @JensV

Comment: I'm pretty confident that the part concerning the activity is only relevant for granting the permission to the app and giving the user the ability to grant it permanently. After that I'm assuming that one should be able to open the serial port from anywhere in the application. I'm thinking that while the activity *might* open when the usb device is plugged in, there's no need to keep it open or in the foreground. First I would just attempt to implement it according to the examples and see if the granting permanently works and go from there.