# Android USB Host. How do I get permission to use USB devices without displaying a dialog?

Tags: android, permissions, usb, host

I have an Android device **without a screen**. When connecting the USB device automatically appears the system dialog to permit the use of USB. It is necessary to obtain a permit **without using the device's screen**.

It is assumed that the device application will be installed in advance, and when the USB device is connected automatically.

How exactly can this be done?

Comment: I don't think you can do that. Think again. wouldn't that be a huge security lack? If a an application uses USB without asking, you can do almost everything. That's not the idea. The android device itself can allow it in the settings but not from your application.

Comment: Maybe there is a way to do this with the help of **root** and install the application as a **system**?

Comment: For the device is supposed to use **USB Host**, and not to connect to a computer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made by analogy in the [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726583/bypass-android-usb-host-permission-confirmation-dialog). Classes for the correct version of SDK took [away](http://grepcode.com/project/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/). I create the necessary packages and copied to the specified and missing classes. The application should be copied into the folder **system/priv-app** and all earned.

Answer (score 4):

Add to activity in manifest file

```
<activity ...>
    ...
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED" />
    </intent-filter>

    <meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED"
        android:resource="@xml/accessory_filter" />
</activity>
```

Create file with params of your usb device in res/xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<resources>
    <usb-accessory manufacturer="Google, Inc." model="DemoKit" version="1.0" />
</resources>
```

Fore more information see https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/accessory.html

Comment: <intent-filter> and <meta-data> added to my device. When you connect USB the system dialog appears for permission, but I need to have permission to receive automatic call without dialog.

Comment: When you connect USB the first time (with already installed app), system call permission dialog. Then another time at start app usb will get permission automatically. If you are using root, watch http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726583/bypass-android-usb-host-permission-confirmation-dialog

Comment: A device **without a screen**, but with a predetermined application. When you connect USB device, I will not be able to press the button "OK" and set the default selection. It is necessary to obtain a permit without having to call for dialogue, even the first time.

Comment: Did everything as in the example, added by analogy missing classes, but my version of Android (4.4.2), I did not get the result.

Comment: Can anyone please explain the components of this answer ?