# Delphi Android requestPermissions - invoke method not found

Tags: android, delphi, mobile, permissions, usb

I try to request LOCATION_HARDWARE permission for reading usb.

in delphi I try this code:

```
    procedure getPermiss;
    var
        LPermissions: TJavaObjectArray<JString>;
    begin
      LPermissions := TJavaObjectArray<JString>.Create(1);
      LPermissions.Items[0] := StringToJString('android.permission.LOCATION_HARDWARE');
      try
        TAndroidHelper.Activity.requestPermissions( LPermissions, 1);
      except
         on E : Exception do
         begin
           ShowMessage('Exception class name = '+E.ClassName+' ' +E.Message);
         end;
      end;
end;
```

but on test in Android Phone show this error:
"JNIFatal: Invoke Method Not Found"

I see that the requestPermissions method of Activity needs 3 parameters, and in delphi needs only 2.

The method signature on AndroidStudio is
requestPermssions(Context, String[], int)

and on delphi is
requestPermissions(String[], int)

hidden the first (Context)

Is this difference the problem? how can I solve ?

Tks

Comment: Please don't tag-spam.  More useful to know would be which Delphi version?

Comment: Regardless of the code not working, you cannot request that permission in an app anyway. Please refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31315355/android-usb-host-how-do-i-get-permission-to-use-usb-devices-without-displaying

Comment: @MartynA Delphi version Tokyo

Comment: @DaveNottage I not want to request permission without dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `requestPermissions( );` was introduced in version `24.1.0` of support library (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.html)

Delphi use by default an old version version of support library so without `requestPermissions( );` implemented. you can however replace the default support library used by delphi with the new one, you can see example at https://github.com/Zeus64/alcinoe