# How to grant USB permissions programmatically on Android Lollipop 5.1

Tags: java, android, usb, ftdi, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I am trying to connect my Android tablet with Lollipop 5.1 installed to a FTDI 232RL USB chip in order to manage a serial communication. I have a problem with the USB permission when I connect the device via USB. There is a way to grant the permission programmatically without touching the dialog that appear when the USB is attached? 
For Android 4.1 I have implemented this solution (the answer of Alvins) and it works perfectly:

[bypass android usb host permission confirmation dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726583/bypass-android-usb-host-permission-confirmation-dialog?noredirect=1&lq=1)

For Android 5.1 I have also tried the following solutions but with no success:

[bypass android usb host permission confirmation dialog for android 5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37048454/bypass-android-usb-host-permission-confirmation-dialog-for-android-5-1)

[USB device access pop-up suppression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12388914/usb-device-access-pop-up-suppression/15151075#15151075)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of – https://stackoverflow.com/q/13726583/1454514