# Android disable default app selection prompt when connect to a usb device

Tags: android, usb, intentfilter

I have an Android app that need to connect to a Usb device. I have used intent filter to get permission to the device, however, every time when I connect phone with the usb device, Android would automatically prompt a selection for default apps that to open with the usb device. I know the all the default apps for the device are determined by activities that have intent filter `<action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />`

So my question is, how can I disable the prompt for the device? No matter the app is open or not, the prompt always show up when device attached which is really annoying to me. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found there is a way to "hack" the prompt.

1. Create a blank activity, add the intent-filter with USB attach filter `<action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />`
2. Remove all other activities's USB Attach intent filter, and add `requestPermission` manually in these activities. Because the blank activity would remember the USB permission for the whole app, so once any these activities grant the USB permission by user, then the whole app is granted. Because now only the blank activity has the USB attach intent filter registered, so this blank activity would be launched by default when USB device plugin
3. In the blank activity `onCreate`, call `onBackPressed` so that once the blank activity is launched, it would automatically go back, and because this is really fast, so the user shouldn't realize any change.

Therefore, when the app is opened, plugin the usb device would just like nothing has happened to user.

Comment: Any better solution, 4 years on?

Comment: @W.M. Unfortunately no, I didn't work on the project since three years ago.

Comment: Actually there is a flawless and simple solution for this issue. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60765997/4185297

Comment: @W.M. Thank you!