# bypass-android-usb-host-permission-confirmation-dialog

Tags: java, android, android-usb

I am trying to bypass usb permissions on android when android is used as host, i followed this link which provides the way to do it on Android 4.x
[bypass android usb host permission confirmation dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726583/bypass-android-usb-host-permission-confirmation-dialog)

This doesn't work on Android 9.0, however. After checking the AOSP source code, it looks like there's quite a few changes for IUsbManager interface. I tried to stub out the new methods that were added, and I had to also create stubs for two more classes under the android.hardware.usb package along the way, name UsbPort and UsbPortStatus.

Here is the code i have for android 9.0, but it doesn't work. I keep getting NoSuchMethod exception when i call grantDevicePermission. The code for ServiceManager.java is the same as in the link so I didn't paste it here.

Help would be appreciated!

IUsbManager interface:

```
package android.hardware.usb;

import android.os.IBinder;

public interface IUsbManager extends android.os.IInterface
{
    /** Local-side IPC implementation stub class. */
    public static abstract class Stub extends android.os.Binder implements android.hardware.usb.IUsbManager
    {
        /** Construct the stub at attach it to the interface. */
        public Stub()
        {
            throw new RuntimeException( "Stub!" );
        }
        /**
         * Cast an IBinder object into an android.hardware.usb.IUsbManager interface,
         * generating a proxy if needed.
         */
        public static android.hardware.usb.IUsbManager asInterface( android.os.IBinder obj )
        {
            throw new RuntimeException( "Stub!" );
        }

    public android.os.IBinder asBinder()
    {
        throw new RuntimeException( "Stub!" );
    }

    public boolean onTransact( int code, android.os.Parcel data, android.os.Parcel reply, int flags ) throws android.os.RemoteException
    {
        throw new RuntimeException( "Stub!" );
    }

    static final int TRANSACTION_getDeviceList = (android.os.IBinder.FIRST_CALL_TRANSACTION + 0);
    static final int TRANSACTION_openDevice = (android.os.IBinder.FIRST_CALL_TRANSACTION + 1);
    static final int TRANSACTION_getCurrentAccessory = (android.os.IBinder.FIRST_CALL_TRANSACTION + 2);
    static final int TRANSACTION_openAccessory = (android.os.IBinder.FIRST_CALL_TRANSACTION + 3);
    static final int TRANSACTION_setDevicePackage = (android.os.IBinder.FIRST_CALL_TRANSACTION + 4);
    static final int TRANSACTION_setAccessoryPackage = (android.os.IBinder.FIRST_CALL_TRANSACTION + 5);
    static final int TRANSACTION_hasDevicePermission = (android.os.IBinder.FIRST_CALL_TRANSACTION + 6);
    static final int TRANSACTION_hasAccessoryPermission = (android.os.IBinder.FIRST_CALL_TRANSACTION + 7);
    static final int TRANSACTION_requestDevicePermission = (android.os.IBinder.FIRST_CALL_TRANSACTION + 8);
    static final int TRANSACTION_requestAccessoryPermission = (android.os.IBinder.FIRST_CALL_TRANSACTION + 9);
    static final int TRANSACTION_grantDevicePermission = (android.os.IBinder.FIRST_CALL_TRANSACTION + 10);
    static final int TRANSACTION_grantAccessoryPermission = (android.os.IBinder.FIRST_CALL_TRANSACTION + 11);
    static final int TRANSACTION_hasDefaults = (android.os.IBinder.FIRST_CALL_TRANSACTION + 12);
    static final int TRANSACTION_clearDefaults = (android.os.IBinder.FIRST_CALL_TRANSACTION + 13);
    static final int TRANSACTION_isFunctionEnabled = (android.os.IBinder.FIRST_CALL_TRANSACTION + 14);
    static final int TRANSACTION_setCurrentFunctions = (android.os.IBinder.FIRST_CALL_TRANSACTION + 15);
    static final int TRANSACTION_setCurrentFunction = (android.os.IBinder.FIRST_CALL_TRANSACTION + 16);
    static final int TRANSACTION_getCurrentFunctions = (android.os.IBinder.FIRST_CALL_TRANSACTION + 17);
    static final int TRANSACTION_setScreenUnlockedFunctions = (android.os.IBinder.FIRST_CALL_TRANSACTION + 18);
    static final int TRANSACTION_getScreenUnlockedFunctions = (android.os.IBinder.FIRST_CALL_TRANSACTION + 19);
    static final int TRANSACTION_getControlFd = (android.os.IBinder.FIRST_CALL_TRANSACTION + 20);
    static final int TRANSACTION_allowUsbDebugging = (android.os.IBinder.FIRST_CALL_TRANSACTION + 21);
    static final int TRANSACTION_denyUsbDebugging = (android.os.IBinder.FIRST_CALL_TRANSACTION + 22);
    static final int TRANSACTION_clearUsbDebuggingKeys = (android.os.IBinder.FIRST_CALL_TRANSACTION + 23);
    static final int TRANSACTION_getPorts = (android.os.IBinder.FIRST_CALL_TRANSACTION + 24);
    static final int TRANSACTION_getPortStatus = (android.os.IBinder.FIRST_CALL_TRANSACTION + 25);
    static final int TRANSACTION_setPortRoles = (android.os.IBinder.FIRST_CALL_TRANSACTION + 26);
    static final int TRANSACTION_setUsbDeviceConnectionHandler = (android.os.IBinder.FIRST_CALL_TRANSACTION + 27);
}

/* Returns a list of all currently attached USB devices */
public void getDeviceList( android.os.Bundle devices ) throws android.os.RemoteException;
/* Returns a file descriptor for communicating with the USB device.
 * The native fd can be passed to usb_device_new() in libusbhost.
 */
public android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor openDevice( java.lang.String deviceName, java.lang.String packageName) throws android.os.RemoteException;
/* Returns the currently attached USB accessory */
public android.hardware.usb.UsbAccessory getCurrentAccessory() throws android.os.RemoteException;
/* Returns a file descriptor for communicating with the USB accessory.
 * This file descriptor can be used with standard Java file operations.
 */
public android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor openAccessory( android.hardware.usb.UsbAccessory accessory ) throws android.os.RemoteException;
/* Sets the default package for a USB device
 * (or clears it if the package name is null)
 */
public void setDevicePackage(android.hardware.usb.UsbDevice device, java.lang.String packageName, int userId) throws android.os.RemoteException;
/* Sets the default package for a USB accessory
 * (or clears it if the package name is null)
 */
public void setAccessoryPackage( android.hardware.usb.UsbAccessory accessory, java.lang.String packageName, int userId ) throws android.os.RemoteException;
/* Returns true if the caller has permission to access the device. */
public boolean hasDevicePermission(android.hardware.usb.UsbDevice device, java.lang.String packageName) throws android.os.RemoteException;
/* Returns true if the caller has permission to access the accessory. */
public boolean hasAccessoryPermission( android.hardware.usb.UsbAccessory accessory ) throws android.os.RemoteException;
/* Requests permission for the given package to access the device.
 * Will display a system dialog to query the user if permission
 * had not already been given.
 */
public void requestDevicePermission( android.hardware.usb.UsbDevice device, java.lang.String packageName, android.app.PendingIntent pi ) throws android.os.RemoteException;
/* Requests permission for the given package to access the accessory.
 * Will display a system dialog to query the user if permission
 * had not already been given. Result is returned via pi.
 */
public void requestAccessoryPermission( android.hardware.usb.UsbAccessory accessory, java.lang.String packageName, android.app.PendingIntent pi ) throws android.os.RemoteException;
/* Grants permission for the given UID to access the device */
public void grantDevicePermission( android.hardware.usb.UsbDevice device, int uid ) throws android.os.RemoteException;
/* Grants permission for the given UID to access the accessory */
public void grantAccessoryPermission( android.hardware.usb.UsbAccessory accessory, int uid ) throws android.os.RemoteException;
/* Returns true if the USB manager has default preferences or permissions for the package */
public boolean hasDefaults( java.lang.String packageName, int userId ) throws android.os.RemoteException;
/* Clears default preferences and permissions for the package */
public void clearDefaults( java.lang.String packageName, int userId ) throws android.os.RemoteException;
/* Returns true if the specified USB function is enabled. */
public boolean isFunctionEnabled(java.lang.String function) throws android.os.RemoteException;
/* Sets the current USB function. */
public void setCurrentFunctions(long functions) throws android.os.RemoteException;
/* Sets the current USB function. */
public void setCurrentFunction( java.lang.String function, boolean usbDataUnlocked ) throws android.os.RemoteException;
/* Gets the current USB functions. */
public long getCurrentFunctions() throws android.os.RemoteException;
/* Sets the screen unlocked USB function(s), which will be set automatically
 * when the screen is unlocked.
 */
public void setScreenUnlockedFunctions(long functions) throws android.os.RemoteException;
/* Gets the current screen unlocked functions. */
public long getScreenUnlockedFunctions() throws android.os.RemoteException;
/* Get the functionfs control handle for the given function. Usb
 * descriptors will already be written, and the handle will be
 * ready to use.
 */
public android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor getControlFd(long function) throws android.os.RemoteException;
/* Allow USB debugging from the attached host. If alwaysAllow is true, add the
 * the public key to list of host keys that the user has approved.
 */
public void allowUsbDebugging(boolean alwaysAllow, java.lang.String publicKey) throws android.os.RemoteException;
/* Deny USB debugging from the attached host */
public void denyUsbDebugging() throws android.os.RemoteException;
/* Clear public keys installed for secure USB debugging */
public void clearUsbDebuggingKeys() throws android.os.RemoteException;
/* Gets the list of USB ports. */
public android.hardware.usb.UsbPort[] getPorts() throws android.os.RemoteException;
/* Gets the status of the specified USB port. */
public android.hardware.usb.UsbPortStatus getPortStatus(java.lang.String portId) throws android.os.RemoteException;
/* Sets the port's current role. */
public void setPortRoles(java.lang.String portId, int powerRole, int dataRole) throws android.os.RemoteException;
/* Sets USB device connection handler. */
public void setUsbDeviceConnectionHandler(android.content.ComponentName usbDeviceConnectionHandler) throws android.os.RemoteException;
}
```

UsbPort.java:

```
package android.hardware.usb;

public class UsbPort implements android.os.Parcelable {

/** @hide */
public UsbPort(String id, int supportedModes) {
    throw new RuntimeException( "Stub!" );
}

/**
 * Gets the unique id of the port.
 *
 * @return The unique id of the port; not intended for display.
 */
public String getId() {
    throw new RuntimeException( "Stub!" );
}

/**
 * Gets the supported modes of the port.
 * <p>
 * The actual mode of the port may vary depending on what is plugged into it.
 * </p>
 *
 */
public int getSupportedModes() {
    throw new RuntimeException( "Stub!" );
}

/**
 * Combines one power and one data role together into a unique value with
 * exactly one bit set.  This can be used to efficiently determine whether
 * a combination of roles is supported by testing whether that bit is present
 * in a bit-field.
 *
 */
public static int combineRolesAsBit(int powerRole, int dataRole) {
    throw new RuntimeException( "Stub!" );
}

/** @hide */
public static String modeToString(int mode) {
    throw new RuntimeException( "Stub!" );
}

/** @hide */
public static String powerRoleToString(int role) {
    throw new RuntimeException( "Stub!" );
}

/** @hide */
public static String dataRoleToString(int role) {
    throw new RuntimeException( "Stub!" );
}

/** @hide */
public static String roleCombinationsToString(int combo) {
    throw new RuntimeException( "Stub!" );
}

/** @hide */
public static void checkMode(int powerRole) {
    throw new RuntimeException( "Stub!" );
}

/** @hide */
public static void checkPowerRole(int dataRole) {
    throw new RuntimeException( "Stub!" );
}

/** @hide */
public static void checkDataRole(int mode) {
    throw new RuntimeException( "Stub!" );
}

/** @hide */
public static void checkRoles(int powerRole, int dataRole) {
    throw new RuntimeException( "Stub!" );
}

/** @hide */
public boolean isModeSupported(int mode) {
    throw new RuntimeException( "Stub!" );
}


@Override
public String toString() {
    throw new RuntimeException( "Stub!" );
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    throw new RuntimeException( "Stub!" );
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(android.os.Parcel dest, int flags) {
    throw new RuntimeException( "Stub!" );
}

public static final android.os.Parcelable.Creator<UsbPort> CREATOR =
        new android.os.Parcelable.Creator<UsbPort>() {
            @Override
            public UsbPort createFromParcel(android.os.Parcel in) {
                throw new RuntimeException( "Stub!" );
            }

            @Override
            public UsbPort[] newArray(int size) {
                throw new RuntimeException( "Stub!" );
            }
        };
}
```

UsbPortStatus.java:

```
package android.hardware.usb;

public class UsbPortStatus implements android.os.Parcelable {

/** @hide */
public UsbPortStatus(int currentMode, int currentPowerRole, int currentDataRole,
                     int supportedRoleCombinations) {
    throw new RuntimeException( "Stub!" );
}

/**
 * Returns true if there is anything connected to the port.
 *
 */
public boolean isConnected() {
    throw new RuntimeException( "Stub!" );
}

/**
 * Gets the current mode of the port.
 *
 */
public int getCurrentMode() {
    throw new RuntimeException( "Stub!" );
}

/**
 * Gets the current power role of the port.
 *
 */
public int getCurrentPowerRole() {
    throw new RuntimeException( "Stub!" );
}

/**
 * Gets the current data role of the port.
 *
 */
public int getCurrentDataRole() {
    throw new RuntimeException( "Stub!" );
}

/**
 * Returns true if the specified power and data role combination is supported
 * given what is currently connected to the port.
 *
 */
public boolean isRoleCombinationSupported(int powerRole, int dataRole) {
    throw new RuntimeException( "Stub!" );
}

/** @hide */
public int getSupportedRoleCombinations() {
    throw new RuntimeException( "Stub!" );
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    throw new RuntimeException( "Stub!" );
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    throw new RuntimeException( "Stub!" );
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(android.os.Parcel dest, int flags) {
    throw new RuntimeException( "Stub!" );
}

public static final android.os.Parcelable.Creator<UsbPortStatus> CREATOR =
        new android.os.Parcelable.Creator<UsbPortStatus>() {
            @Override
            public UsbPortStatus createFromParcel(android.os.Parcel in) {
                throw new RuntimeException( "Stub!" );
            }

            @Override
            public UsbPortStatus[] newArray(int size) {
                throw new RuntimeException( "Stub!" );
            }
        };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's new restrictions on non-SDK interfaces (Android 9): https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/restrictions-non-sdk-interfaces

Can be solved by:

```
adb shell
su
settings put global hidden_api_policy_pre_p_apps  1
settings put global hidden_api_policy_p_apps 1
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57622623/7767664