# Android 10 bypass USB Dialog Permission

Tags: android, permissions, usb

i wnat to disable usb permission dialog when i am connecting my device via usb,
how can i bypass it?
i know [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726583/bypass-android-usb-host-permission-confirmation-dialog) works for android 4, but what should i do in android 10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57390558/bypass-android-usb-host-permission-confirmation-dialog-on-android-9) and added this command to terminal

to use non-sdk api's in android 10:

```
Adb shell  settings put global hidden_api_policy 1
```