# USB Host Mode - device access permission granted but not remembered

Tags: android, usb, host

I have a USB Host Mode application that works perfectly.  I plug in the device, Android pops up the **Allow the app APPNAME to access the USB device?** permission request window, I check the **Use by default for this USB device** tick box and tap **OK**, then up comes my app and it communicates with the USB device perfectly.

BUT...

Then I unplug the device and plug it back in.  Android pops up the **Allow the app APPNAME to access the USB device?** dialog again.  WTH?  I've already told Android to do this by default, so why is it asking me again?

This happens both with Icecream Sandwich 4.0.3 and Jellybean 4.1.

Ideally I want Android to remember I've granted permission for this particular USB device even after I've rebooted the Android device.

So why isn't Android remembering that I've granted permission?

Comment: possible duplicate of [USB device access pop-up supression?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12388914/usb-device-access-pop-up-supression)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a dup of [USB device access pop-up supression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12388914/usb-device-access-pop-up-supression).  Basically the answer is to use an intent-filter on USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED and steer clear of the RequestPermission USB Host Mode API call.

Comment: Use the intent-filter as described in the linked question, not RequestPermission.

Comment: I have used intent filter but it is asking for permission

Answer (score 4):

I answered this [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/39851/how-to-stop-android-asking-for-permission-before-permitting-access-to-usb-device/41090#41090), although I gather that duplicates across other SE sites are permitted.

In answer to *why*, it is as you surmised in said thread; because with your hardware you get different identifiers each time you connect, e.g. /dev/bus/usb/001/, /dev/bus/usb/002/ and so on.

Answer (score 2):

The Android just cannot remember my grant for my device But fortunately, I figured out the reason: I used hex values in the device_filter.xml. After I changed it to **decimal values**, everything just works fine. My Android can remember my permit then.