# Android Usb Host, singleInstance, onCreate keeps getting called with USB attach

Tags: android, usb, oncreate, single-instance

I have an application that uses a proprietary USB device (android in host mode).

I have a `BroadcastReceiver` which I register in the constructor

```
// this block is in the constructor
usbConnectionReceiver = new UsbConnectionReceiver();
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED);
filter.addAction(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED);
context.registerReceiver(usbConnectionReceiver, filter);



public class UsbConnectionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED.equals(action)) {
            UsbDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            if (device != null) onDeviceAttached(device);
        } else if (UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED.equals(action)) {
            UsbDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            if (device != null) onDeviceDetached(device);
        }
    }
}

public void onDeviceAttached(UsbDevice device) {
    usbDevice = device;
    intf = usbDevice.getInterface(0);
    endpoint = intf.getEndpoint(0);
    if (usbManager.hasPermission(usbDevice)) {
        usbDeviceConnection = usbManager.openDevice(usbDevice);
        boolean status = usbDeviceConnection.claimInterface(intf, true);
        if (status) {
            startPollingThread();
        }
    } else {
        // I used to have code here that would programmatically prompt for permissions.
    }
}
```

Everything works great, except that every time the device is detached and reattached, the end-user is prompted for permissions. 
The "Use by default for this USB device" checkbox is completely ignored.

After some research, it appears that if I ask for permissions via code, that is indeed the case.

So I've switched my activity to use an intent filter.  I no longer get the permissions box after the first time, so the checkbox is working.  Instead, every time the device is reattached, it calls `onCreate()` of my app, crashing it.

I have the `launchMode="singleInstance"` (in fact, I've tried all varieties), and while the app is up and running and top on the screen, the `onCreate()` is called instead of the `onNewIntent()` (which the documentation seems to suggest should happen).

I also read that I need to set `android:launchMode="singleInstance"`
I also read I need to set `android:taskAffinity=""`

All to no avail.  I know there are tons of similar posts, but none of them seem to work.  Any advice is appreciated.

Here is my **AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.me.myapp" >
    <application
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:taskAffinity=""
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="keyboard" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
                android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the best solution ... if anyone has a comment, I'd love to hear it because Usb handling in android has always been a headache!

I used this post as a reference [USB device access pop-up supression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12388914/usb-device-access-pop-up-supression)

I created the following Activity

```
public class UsbActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "UsbActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (intent != null)
        {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED))
            {
                Logger.lc(TAG,"ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED");
                UsbDevice usbDevice = intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                Logger.lc(TAG,"UsbDevice");
                UsbManager usbManager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
                Logger.lc(TAG,"UsbManager");
                if (usbDevice != null && usbManager != null && !usbManager.hasPermission(usbDevice)) {
                    Logger.lc(TAG,"openDevice");
                    usbManager.openDevice(usbDevice);
                }
            }
        }
        finish();
    }
}
```

And added it to the manifest

```
<activity
        android:name="com.myapp.UsbActivity"
        android:label="MyApp"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:taskAffinity="com.myapp.taskAffinityUsbReceiver"
        android:process=":UsbEventReceiverActivityProcess"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
            android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />
</activity>
```

with the following style.xml

```
   <style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
   </style>
```