# USB device not usable until reconnected after app has been opened

Tags: java, android

So to alleviate the issue of having to grant permission every time the app is launched, I've followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15151075/2220763)

So I have my device filter setup

```
<resources>
    <usb-device vendor-id="1234" product-id="5678" />
</resources>
```

The activity in the manifest

```
    <activity
        android:name=".demo.Activity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_demo"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
            android:resource="@xml/usb_device_filter" />
    </activity>
```

Then in my java file

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mUsbReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
{
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (ACTION_USB_PERMISSION.equals(action))
        {
            synchronized (this)
            {
                UsbDevice device = (UsbDevice)intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                if(device != null)
                {
                   checkDevice();
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION);
mContext.registerReceiver(mUsbReceiver, filter);
```

If I start the app with the device connected, it doesn't light up and the API for the device won't communicate with it (it does show in the `UsbManager.getDeviceList()` call, however)

As soon as I physically remove it and plug it back in again, it works

Is there a way I can 'reconnect' the device programatically, or some other fix? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

check if device exist in the device list on app start.

```
UsbManager manager = (UsbManager) context.getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
Iterator devices = manager.getDeviceList().entrySet().iterator();
while (devices.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) devices.next();
    Log.i(TAG, pair.getKey() + " = " + pair.getValue());

    UsbDevice device = (UsbDevice) pair.getValue();
    Log.i(TAG, "UsbDevice: " + device.toString());
    if(device.getVendorId() == 1234 && device.getProductId() == 5678) {

    }
}
```

Comment: It does, I've also tried opening and closing a connection via the UsbManager