# How to use the USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED intent-filter in Android for a USB device that is always connected

Tags: android, permissions, usb, android-permissions, intentfilter

I have a scenario where I want an app to open when it detects that it's connected to a USB device. I have used an approach similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12388914/usb-device-access-pop-up-suppression/15151075#15151075) (it is using a USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED intent-filter and I have the ID's defined in an xml) and it is working for the most part. The problem I'm having is that when the Android Tablet powers on, the tablet will already be connected to the USB device, so the app doesn't get the USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED event. This then requires me to start the app manually after power up, which leads to me getting this unwanted dialog screen each time:

> Allow App to access USB?
>
> [ ] Always open App when USB is connected
>
> Cancel    OK

It makes no difference if I check the "Always open" box. It still shows up each time. I have tried using a broadcast receiver to open the app when the app powers on, and I still get the dialog window.

So I'm wondering:

- Is there is a way to see get a USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED event when I first power on?
- Or is there a way to not display the unwanted dialog screen each time I open the app manually?

I would really appreciate any suggestions. Thanks!